# sequelize rollback isnot working when new error throw

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, rollback

I'm trying to update three tables at ones as a transaction. if one of table doesn't update I want to rollback it. I tried manually the executed queries in MySQL database and it works fine. But in the code, it doesn't work properly and not rolling back.

here is the code,

```
return sequelize.transaction({
    autocommit: false
}, function(t) {
    return models.VaccinationCenter.update({
        email
    }, {
        where: {
            id: vacId
        }
    }, {
        transaction: t
    }).then(function(VaccinationCenter) {
        //console.log('---------------VaccinationCenter--------------------------------',VaccinationCenter)
        if (VaccinationCenter[0] === 0) {
            throw new Error();
            //console.log('VaccinationCenter--------------error')
        } else {
            return models.Person.update({
                    email
                }, {
                    where: {
                        email: prevEmail
                    }
                }, {
                    transaction: t
                })
                .then(function(Person) {
                    //console.log('---------------Person--------------------------------',Person);
                    if (Person[0] === 0) {
                        //console.log('Person--------------error');
                        throw new Error();
                    } else {
                        return models.User.update({
                                email
                            }, {
                                where: {
                                    email: prevEmail
                                }
                            }, {
                                transaction: t
                            })
                            .then(function(User) {
                                if (User[0] === 0) {
                                    //console.log('User--------------error');
                                    throw new Error();
                                } else {
                                    callback({
                                        statusCode: Constants.errorStatus.SUCCESS,
                                        body: {
                                            isValidemail: true
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                //console.log('---------------User--------------------------------',User)
                            });
                    }

                });
        }

    });

}).then(result => {
    callback({
        statusCode: Constants.errorStatus.SUCCESS,
        body: {
            isValidemail: true
        }
    });

}).catch(error => {
    callback({
        statusCode: Constants.errorStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        body: {
            isValidEmail: false
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the console when running this code.

```
Executing (f4d0d13f-d72e-4cb7-bd1b-c26e6ceddaca): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (f4d0d13f-d72e-4cb7-bd1b-c26e6ceddaca): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
Executing (f4d0d13f-d72e-4cb7-bd1b-c26e6ceddaca): SET autocommit = 0;
Executing (default): UPDATE `VaccinationCenters` SET `email`='devakadabare1+12@gmail.com',`updatedAt`='2020-03-03 10:06:14' WHERE `id` = 60
Executing (default): UPDATE `People` SET `email`='devakadabare1+12@gmail.com',`updatedAt`='2020-03-03 10:06:14' WHERE `email` = 'devakadabare1+11@gmail.com'
Executing (f4d0d13f-d72e-4cb7-bd1b-c26e6ceddaca): ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the managed transaction you should never commit or rollback the transaction manually. If all queries are successful, but you still want to rollback the transaction (for example because of a validation failure) you should throw an error to break and reject the chain. For example:

```
return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Abraham',
    lastName: 'Lincoln'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
    // Woops, the query was successful but we still want to roll back!
    throw new Error();
  });
});
```

For more detail, check the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/transactions/)

Comment: it s work when replace this code `where: {
                        email: prevEmail
                    }
                }, {
                    transaction: t
                }`   with  `where: {
                        email: prevEmail
                    }, transaction: t
                `